# Placement of objects displaced every 2nd row

Tags: algorithm

Im looking for a way to place objects displaced from each other on every 2nd row.

The objects are being placed like this: http://bit.ly/fpn1GC

```
for(var i:uint=1;i<12;i++) {
    for(var j:uint=1;j<12;j++) {
        var p:place = new place();

        if(i%2){
            //1-3-5...
            p.x=40*j;
        }
        else {
            //2-4-6...
            p.x=40*j;
        }
        p.y=29*i;
        addChild(p);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: add and subtract from p.x in your if else cases?

Comment: if substract/add the position between each object is made smaller/larger than from the other row

Comment: I'm assuming p.x is the x position of item p.  If it's the size, then I don't know what you're doing.  Shift every other row by a certain amount, and you'll end up with the kind of pattern you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(var i:uint=0;i<11;i++) {
    for(var j:uint=0;j<11;j++) {
        var p:place = new place();

        if(i%2){
            //2-4-6...
            p.x=42*j+22;
        }
        else {
            //1-3-5...
            p.x=42*j+42;
        }
        p.y=28*i+20;
        addChild(p);
    }
}
```